# Submiting data from Excel to Access

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, ms-access

I have multiple excel files sent to me daily. Each one is identical and contains the daily logs of construction foremen. On these excel sheets I have a tables that the foreman update daily with their new information. I want to be able to pool all of the data from these tables in access and use the access reports function to create daily reports for the groups of foremen.

If there is not a better way to do this, how can I either import or export this information from multiple spreadsheets into one table on access?

If this could also be done in SQL server remotely by the foreman that would also be nice to know.

Edit: The special difficulty I am facing is access only allowing me to select the sheet the table is on and not the table itself. The sheet has more information on it other than the table. Is there a way to select the specific table when importing? Also, I wanted to be able to program this in VBA so I could press a button on the excel sheet to export to my access database

Comment: Write a stored procedure in T-SQL and put it on a timer.

Comment: If these worksheets conform to the layout of a table, the `import` feature of Access is straightforward. What is the special difficulty you are facing?

Comment: The special difficulty I am facing is access only allowing me to select the sheet the table is on and not the table itself. The sheet has more information on it other than the table. Is there a way to select the specific table when importing? Also, I wanted to be able to program this in VBA so I could press a button on the excel sheet to export to my access database.

Comment: What do you mean by 'table' on the sheet - do you mean a range?

Answer (score 0):

I use this code.

```
Sub ExportToAccess()
    Dim PathOfAccess As String, myFn As String
    Dim strConn As String, strSQL As String


    PathOfAccess = "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Database1.accdb"
    myFn = ThisWorkbook.FullName

    strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & PathOfAccess & ";"

    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    cn.Open strConn

strSQL = "INSERT  INTO table1  select * from [Sheet1$] IN '' " _
  & "[Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=2;DATABASE=" & myFn & "]"

cn.Execute strSQL


End Sub

Sub ImportFromAccess()

    Dim Rs As Object
    Dim strConn As String, strSQL As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim PathOfAccess As String


    PathOfAccess = "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Database1.accdb"

    strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & PathOfAccess & ";"

    Set Rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM table1 "
    Rs.Open strSQL, strConn

    Set Ws = ActiveSheet

    If Not Rs.EOF Then
         With Ws
            .Range("a1").CurrentRegion.ClearContents
            For i = 0 To Rs.Fields.Count - 1
               .Cells(1, i + 1).Value = Rs.Fields(i).Name
            Next
            .Range("a" & 2).CopyFromRecordset Rs
        End With
    End If
    Rs.Close
    Set Rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily export data from Excel to Access.

```
Sub DAOFromExcelToAccess()
' exports data from the active worksheet to a table in an Access database
' this procedure must be edited before use
Dim db As Database, rs As Recordset, r As Long
    Set db = OpenDatabase("C:\FolderName\DataBaseName.mdb") 
    ' open the database
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("TableName", dbOpenTable) 
    ' get all records in a table
    r = 3 ' the start row in the worksheet
    Do While Len(Range("A" & r).Formula) > 0 
    ' repeat until first empty cell in column A
        With rs
            .AddNew ' create a new record
            ' add values to each field in the record
            .Fields("FieldName1") = Range("A" & r).Value
            .Fields("FieldName2") = Range("B" & r).Value
            .Fields("FieldNameN") = Range("C" & r).Value
            ' add more fields if necessary...
            .Update ' stores the new record
        End With
        r = r + 1 ' next row
    Loop
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    db.Close
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

' THIS RUNS IN EXCEL

Now, if you want to IMPORT data from multiple Excel files (in a single folder, I presume), you can try the script below.

```
Dim strPathFile As String, strFile As String, strPath As String
 Dim strTable As String
 Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean

' Change this next line to True if the first row in EXCEL worksheet
 ' has field names
 blnHasFieldNames = False

' Replace C:\Documents\ with the real path to the folder that
 ' contains the EXCEL files
 strPath = "C:\Documents\"

' Replace tablename with the real name of the table into which 
 ' the data are to be imported
 strTable = "tablename"

 strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls")
 Do While Len(strFile) > 0
       strPathFile = strPath & strFile
       DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
             strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames

' Uncomment out the next code step if you want to delete the 
 ' EXCEL file after it's been imported
 '       Kill strPathFile

       strFile = Dir()
 Loop
' THIS RUNS IN ACCESS
```